# how to create working test cases for springboot application REST using Jersey Framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, spring-boot-test

I have the controller class in spring boot with Jersey as below, using mockito to mock the controller class and mockMvc as well.

```
@GET
@Path("/parameters")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static modelClass DoSomething(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("dob") String dob)
            throws IOException {

modelClassobject = ServiceClassobject.getdetails(name, dob);
}
```

I have the following test for this using mocks

```
    @Mock
    private modelClass object1;

    @Mock
    private serviceclass object2;

    @InjectMocks
    private controllerclass object3;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockObject = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(object3).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDetails() throws Exception {
ModelClass object4 = new ModelClass();
object4.setname("somename");
object4.setdob("23-4-1856");

Mockito.when(object3.getdetails(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(object4);

mockmvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/parameters")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

Once I run this as a unit test, I get

```
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET
```

I have tried to implement other ways as well, but all result in the same error. How do I get the endpoints?

Comment: MockMvc will only work with Spring MVC controllers, not a Jersey application, You will need to make an actual Http request with an Http client like the Jersey Client, RestTemplate, WebClient, etc. As an aside, please use Java naming convention, i.e.  class names begin with capital letters and method names begin with lowercase. Also do not make your resource methods static.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your method with @GET annotation

```
@GET
@Path("/parameters")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static modelClass DoSomething(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("dob") String dob)
            throws IOException {

modelClassobject = ServiceClassobject.getdetails(name, dob);
}
```

Please refer to this: https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-example-jersey

Comment: Sorry, formatting issue. I already have the @GET annotation in there.